# Send input values to redirect page after form submission in HTML page without Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

We have an employment application that is submitting to a specific URL to archive the results into our internal document management software.  It requires that we use a standard HTML page (versus .aspx or some other server side page).

If the user doesn't have javascript enabled, they should still be able to submit an application.  I have a requirement that I break out the "optional" form fields (race, etc) so they are not included in the regular application.  On the optional form I need the values from the original app such as name, email, position applying for, etc.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get these values from the original application page to the second form on the redirect page.

Workflow: Original HTML page for app submits to internal URL to archive the results then redirects back out to the second form to collect the optional information which submits back to the internal URL to archive those as well which redirects back out to a success page.

Original HTML Page which redirects to https://xxxx.com/optional.html

```
<form id="obrequest" method="post" action="https://obweb.xxxx.com/loginformproc.aspx?fromloginformproc=true">
<input type="hidden" name="OBDocumentType" value="1554" />
<input type="hidden" name="OBWeb_FinalTargetPage" value="https://xxxx.com/optional.html">
<table width="96%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>READ FIRST: All qualified applicants will receive consideration for employment without regard to status as a protected veteran or a qualified individual with a disability, or other protected status, such as race, religion, color, national origin, sex, age.</p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal information</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="fm-firstname">
                            First name:</label>
                        <input name="103_1" type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus required />
                    </li>
etc....</form></html>
```

How do I get fm-firstname value to the optional.html page after form submission without using javascript?  Or how do I make sure that we capture the form submission regardless if the browser has javascript enabled or not before using it to send data to the optional form?

Comment: Are you able to use PHP? Sorry, scratch that. Just saw your .aspx comment

Comment: I was considering writing a cookie then reading the values out of it for the optional field, but if the user has cookies turned off I guess we still get the app but no optional values.  Might be best case scenario?

Comment: Yes, cookies would suffice. However like you stated, it would fail if the user has them disabled. I guess it's the best case scenario like you said.

Comment: You don't. You tell them you need the proper tools.

Comment: What do you suggest Joe?